# best way to fetch NFT metadata from frontend?

Tags: anchor, frontend

what's the best way to get nft metadata like image & name etc?

like input your nft mint address & it emits the nft metadata

-- any API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

metaplex SDK: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js

it sounds like the `findByMint` method is what you're looking to do

[image]